# load differents image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to show differents image depending of variable value. if the user.ima variable is empty must show defaultImg variable.

```
<img class="" ng-src="{{this value depend of user.ima if empty then load defaultimg}}" width="60px" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a method:

```
$scope.GetImgUrl = function(){
   if(!$scope.user.ima)
   {
      return $scope.defaultImgUrl;
   }

   return $scope.user.ima;
}
```

And:

```
<img class="" ng-src="{{GetImgUrl()}}" />
```